# Two clients communicate and exchange messages with server java socket

Tags: java, sockets

Sorry if its a duplicate question but I did not find the answer to my problem.

I have two clients A.java and B.java. How the server will know which of the two clients has sent a message without using Thread?

Server Code:

```
      try {

           ServerSocket ServerSocket=new ServerSocket(25000);
           System.out.println("Connect to the port 25000");

           while(true)
           {

               Socket socket=ServerSocket.accept();
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
               String str = br.readLine();//msg from client A or B
               System.out.println(str);

           }
       }

       catch (Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Error");
       }
```

Client Code:( Both Clients have the same code in their class (ClientA.java or ClientB.java))

```
    try {
        Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",25000);

        DataOutputStream outToServer=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes("Hello from ClientA" + '\n');(or Client B)

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

Comment: Your server will only read line from one client before dropping the connection and reading a line from the next client. Did you want to be able to read from multiple clients at once?

Comment: Yes i want to be able to read and process a message from multiple clients at once and distinguish which of the client is.

Comment: In that case I suggest you use a cached ExecutorService Thread pool and create a handler to read/write from the socket.  As each thread only reads from one socket, you know which socket you just read from.

Comment: Is there a way without using threads?

Comment: Why don't you want to use threads? And why do you have two different classes with same code?

Comment: Yes, you can use NIO non-blocking selectors, however this is much more advanced and 10x harder.  I would only suggest you do this if you are 100% confident with using threads to do it first.  An alternative is to use a library like netty which does much of the work ad thinking for you.  You might find it easier.

Comment: One is the publisher client and one is the subscriber client and my requirements of the exercise saying that we must not use Threads

Comment: If you use NIO (or netty) classes like *Reader and *Stream cannot be used as these have blocking operations.

Comment: If this is an assignment, then the person giving the task has a very specific solution in mind, one you can't just guess.  I suggest you ask the person giving the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one thread to get connections and one thread to receive messages.
Otherwyse your application is blocked waiting for new connections and you can't do nothing else.
But you don't need a thread for each client. If you add the socket to a list for each connected client you can loop through all client with a code similar to this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sockets.size(); i++) {
    try {
        Socket socket = sockets.get(i);
        if (socket.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
            // TODO: read data from socket
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: Handle the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Non-blocking is about the only option to do it all in one thread, but it has the downside that your threads must busy wait for input (Unless you use NIO selectors), and you can't use classes like BufferedReader which blocks. +1

Comment: It is a design decision depending on the number of possible clients. If the application should handle many thousands of clients manage them with one thread each is a very heavy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NIO with asynchronous capability.

On server side:

```
ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8888));
serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
for (;;) {
    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
    if (socketChannel != null){
      //here you can use socketChannel
    }
}
```

And on the clien side:

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8888));
while(! socketChannel.finishConnect() ){
    //wait here to finish and do something
}
```